# Vue 3: Use GSAP to animate component in app.vue

Tags: animation, vuejs3, gsap

Below is how I animate elements in a component with GSAP. Is there a way for me to control the animation in 'app.vue' instead?

```
<template>
  <h1 ref="main" class="hello">Hello, GSAP!</h1>
</template>

<script setup>
onMounted(() => {
  ctx = gsap.context(() => {
   
    tl = gsap
      .timeline()
      .to(".hello", { x: 120, rotation: 360 });
  }, main.value); // 
});

onUnmounted(() => {
  ctx.revert(); 
});
</script>
```

This is what I'm expecting:

**My Component:**

```
<template>
  <h1 ref="main" class="hello">Hello, GSAP!</h1>
</template>
```

**app.vue**

```
<template>
    <AnimateMe ref="main">
</template>
  
<script setup>
onMounted(() => {
  ctx = gsap.context(() => {
   
    tl = gsap
      .timeline()
      .to(".hello", { x: 120, rotation: 360 });
  }, main.value); // 
});

onUnmounted(() => {
  ctx.revert(); 
});

</script>
```

The code I provided works but It's incoherent